# How to sort DataSet by column

Tags: c#, sql

My SQL database was created in SQL Server Management Studio. I have a dataset table that works great, which was sorted by the primary key id column from an example I copied, which was fine when there were only a few entries. Now I want to sort by the Model_no column.

I have tried to sort the table like this:

```
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "Model_no";
```

and like this:

```
DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
DataView view = table.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "Model_no";
```

But the table is still sorted by primaryKey.

```
objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
conString = "Server=VENUS;" +
"Initial Catalog=TestRig;" +
"User id=TestRig;" +
"Password=act1ve;" +
"MultipleActiveResultSets = true;";

objConnect.connection_string = conString;
objConnect.Sql = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL;

ds = objConnect.GetConnection;

DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];  // Neither this 
DataView view = table.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "Model_no";

// ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "Model_no";  // or this work

// When I click next record, I inc the row, then get the datarow and 
display in my form
inc++;
dRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[inc];

dummy = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();  // Primary Id

exVol = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
tbExcitationVoltage.Text = exVol.Trim();
```

When I open the form I expect the first entry to be sorted by the model number, but instead see record 1 (primary ID), how can I sort by another column please?

Comment: Changes you make to the view should be accessed through the view, not the original table

Comment: You are sorting the `dataview`, but you are reading from the `dataTable`. After sorting the `dataview`, you have to read from it: `dataview.ToTable().Rows`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read from DefaultView. If you need to read from the table you can do the following.

```
  ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "Model_no";
  DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Comment: The [`DataTableCollection` indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatablecollection.item?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataTableCollection_Item_System_Int32_) is readonly. Also, you can't use `s.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable()` if you want to sort it. You are missing the essential part `view.Sort = "Model_no"`

Comment: @Rango That was already part of his answer, which is why I skipped it . But thanks for pointing out the readonly part. I somehow missed it when answering